# Using ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers in a standard web forms project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, html-helper

So for example in the code behind of a web form aspx page I would like to be able to do things like

string textBoxHtml = Html.TextBox("MyTextBox");

Is this possible?

Is the source code available to fork for webforms?

Comment: Yes, I want to do this with @Html.Partial(), toward the goal of reusing header HTML markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Possible?  Yes.
2. The entire MVC source is available at:
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Good luck!

You'll quickly find that pulling bits of code out of MVC is like only wanting a banana and getting the gorilla holding it.  ;)

Comment: Where are the poachers when we need them?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that is working for me so far.

```
public static class PageCommon
{
    public static System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper GetUrlHelper(this System.Web.UI.Control c)
    {
        var helper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(c.Page.Request.RequestContext);
        return helper;
    }
    class ViewDataBag : IViewDataContainer
    {
        ViewDataDictionary vdd = new ViewDataDictionary();
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
        {
            get
            {
                return vdd;
            }
            set
            {
                vdd = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public static System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper GetHtmlHelper(this System.Web.UI.Control c)
    {
        IViewDataContainer x;

        var v = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext();
        var helper = new System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(v, new ViewDataBag());
        return helper;
    }
```

Comment: Using this helper to render an input like this: <%= this.GetHtmlHelper().TextBox("textBox") %>, gives a NRE: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name) +43

Any ideas what's missing?

Comment: in debug, what exactly is null?

Comment: Depends what ext method you use: for .TextBox(..) that'll be HttpContext (this is where it tries to get value from), for .BeginForm it will be .Writer property (so it can render opening/closing HTML tags). Final class might looks smth like: https://gist.github.com/esteewhy/6450385