# How to access HTML Helpers(from mvc) in **WEB FORMS**?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, html-helper

There are a lot of discussions on how to merge webforms with mvc.

Can anyone give me details on how to use the mvc Html Helpers with webforms?(using .vb)

I'd like to go `<%=Html.______%>`

the underlined portion should give me intellisense..

We've been googling stackoverflow for hours with no success. Every similar post redirects to [Scott Hanselman's blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) or a similar post.

Can think of no other 'easy solution' other than go back to mvc, use the fact that mvc and webforms are basically .NET and try to hack our way through somehow, because there's no way we're rewriting all of that webforms stuff into mvc.. 
we hope...

Help!!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073378/using-asp-net-mvc-html-helpers-in-a-standard-web-forms-project). IMO, you'll waste time trying to make the two work together on a single page (no problems using MVC/Web Forms in a single project). If your Web Forms solution is stable, focus on writing new features in MVC and slowly migrating. If it's not stable, adding HTML helpers probably isn't going to improve much.