# How do I use Html Extensions in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, html-helper

I currently have a Web Forms application which I'd like to use the MVC Html helpers for.  Ex, I'd like to use Html.SelectList instead of the asp:DropDownList control due to the nature of not being able to specify a name property for that control if it's within a master page.

Would I need to import some Nuget packages to get to the Mvc Html helpers and the SelectList class?

Comment: It looks like an answer already exists:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073378/using-asp-net-mvc-html-helpers-in-a-standard-web-forms-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073378/using-asp-net-mvc-html-helpers-in-a-standard-web-forms-project) posted to your comment just said it is possible.

My answer is not worth it.

Mainly, ASP.Net Web Form is event based model. You cannot access it easily in code behind, even if you can render Select html like MVC Helper.

ASP.Net Web Form doesn't have model binder like MVC. So when post back, only way you can access that html selector is to search in **Form** directly - `var mySelector = Request.Form["MySelector"];`

Comment: You win the answer contest by default, sir.  SO wouldn't let me post a "Trivial" answer and forced it as a comment.