# Html does not exist in current context. Can I use html class in web forms using Web View syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am programming an app that has some sections in WebForms and some in MVC.  I have a Webform.master and a Site.Master.  When using the Html class, My Webform.master in visual studio says "The name html does not exist in the current context." but I don't get that error in site.master file, and html is used many times there.

Both the site.master and webform.master are in the views/shared directory.

EDIT: my purpose is to render a partial view in webforms.  I'm unable to do that because html is not recognized in webform.master.  If there's an alternate way to render a partial view, I'd use that if possible.

This is the Webform.master.

```
<%@ Master 
Language="C#" 
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Root.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Webform.master.cs" 
Inherits="JCIMS_MVC2_EF.WebUI.Views.Shared.Webform"
%>

<%@ Register src="SupportPartial.ascx" tagname="SupportPartial" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

This is the Site.master.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Root.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Html` methods are all part of the [HtmlHelper class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) which is a feature of MVC.

The first line of `site.Master` is telling your page to inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage` which will give you access to the MVC namespace and the HtmlHelper you're looking for.

```xml
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Root.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

Your `Webform.master` page inherits from `JCIMS_MVC2_EF.WebUI.Views.Shared.Webform` as you can see from the first line. So you will not be able to use the HtmlHelper here.

```xml
<%@ Master 
Language="C#" 
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Root.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Webform.master.cs" 
Inherits="JCIMS_MVC2_EF.WebUI.Views.Shared.Webform"
%>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I apologize, but I forgot to mention my main goal in the question. I am trying to render a partial view. But as you've shown, the Html helper isn't accessible to the webform.master class. Since I cannot use the helper, is there another way I can render the partial?

Comment: Most direct method to bypass the block would be to use [jQuery's .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load it via an HTTP request; you could also use a vanilla JS method to do something similar if you don't have/want jQuery in your project. If you're set on using the `HtmlHelper` you could try creating your own HtmlHelper since it has a few public constructors, but that may be more challenging than it's worth. [See this question for a few possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073378/using-asp-net-mvc-html-helpers-in-a-standard-web-forms-project)